# I'm getting an error that I don't understand and can't fix on my own using Swift. My question is different. Look at the code I've provided. Thank you

Tags: ios, swift

Getting an Expected declaration error and my build fails.

Learning how to code using Swift and ran into an error. It won't build my app because of this error. There is another question that is similar to mine and has the same error but the code is completely different from mine. Thank you to everyone who tried to help me out!

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {


    @IBOutlet weak var leftImageView: UIImageView!

    @IBOutlet weak var RightImageView: UIImageView!

    @IBOutlet weak var leftScoreLabel: UILabel!

    @IBOutlet weak var rightScoreLabel: UILabel!

    var leftScore = 0
    var rightScore = 0

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()

        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    @IBAction func dealTapped(_ sender: Any) {

        // randomize two numbers

        let leftRandomNumber = arc4random_uniform(13) + 2


        let rightRandomNumber = arc4random_uniform(13) + 2

        //Change the image views

        leftImageView.image = UIImage(named: "card\(leftRandomNumber)")
        RightImageView.image = UIImage(named: "card\(rightRandomNumber)")
    }

 // Getting an error on the line of code below

    if leftRandomNumber > rightRandomNumber {
        leftScore += 1
    leftScoreLabel.text = String(leftScore)
    }
    else if rightRandomNumber > leftRandomNumber {
    rightScore += 1

    rightScoreLabel.text = String(rightScore)
}
    else if leftRandomNumber == rightRandomNumber {

}
}
```

Comment: Count the opening and closing braces or look at the indentation of the code and you'll see the error at once. Or press and hold  ⌘ and hover over an opening brace to see its closing counterpart

Comment: Will do and thank you for taking the time out to answer my question! Much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like your code snippet where you get the error is outside a method. You should put that snippet at least inside a function. Maybe you can try to put it inside the IBAction function dealTapped.

Comment: Will try that out. Thank you so much for answering my question and for helping me out. :-)